# Passing object to edit page and maintaining changes

Tags: flutter

I have a custom object called item, which contains parameters such as a name, description, price etc. My app's home page is a streambuilder of item objects (stored in Firestore). When I click on an item, it takes me to a detail page, and from there, I can hit another button to edit the item's parameters. When navigating from the home page (item list) to the item detail page, I am using `fromMap` to easily create a local item from the database and passing that item into the detail page. Then, if the user decides to click the edit button, I am passing that same item into the item edit page (with the item's parameters already filled out). My edit page also contains a button 'save' that will save the updated parameters to Firestore.

The issue I am facing is that this local item is being shared between the detail page and the edit page. So for example if I edit the name of an item and hit the back button, those changes will be reflected in the detail page, when I actually don't want them to. What is the best way of going about handling these changes, more specifically updating the item parameter's in the detail page? Should I add a method in the detail page that every time I enter this page, refresh the page by pulling the most recent data from Firestore? Or, when navigating from the home page (item list) to the detail page, pass in the item's document ID and create the item in the detail page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a copy of the item object and edit the copy instead so they do not share the same reference.

At the end when you want to propagate the change you can just set the values of the newly instantiated object to the old one.

For example:

```
class EditItemDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;

  EditItemDetailsPage([this.item]);

  @override
  _EditItemDetailsPageState createState() => _EditItemDetailsPageState();
}

...

class _EditItemDetailsPageState extends State<EditItemDetailsPage> {
  Item _itemCopy;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Make a copy of the instance you are editing
    // An easy way to copy is to convert them into a map and back.
    itemCopy = Item().fromMap(widget.item.toMap());

    // Now your widgets here will edit _itemCopy instead of widget.item
  }

  void submit() {
    // Send to firestore  
    bool success = sendToFirestore();

    // Change were made to firestore successfully
    if (success) {
      // Apply change to original account instance.
      widget.item.fromMap(_itemCopy.toMap());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool. I had something like this in mind but I was unsure if I should make the copy before I call Navigator.push or inside the edit item class. I will go with your solution